# Unique 6 digit number but not sequential for Customer ID (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, random, numbers

Our Customer table has an int Identity column for ID. This was going to be given out to customers, so when they phone they could just give their ID.

It is now obvious that our competitors would easily be able to register twice on our site, say a month apart and find out exactly how many people have registered.

Therefore, is there a nice simple way to create a "Customer ID" (in SQL or c#) which we could give to customers that is:
(a) 6 digits long
(b) is unique
(c) is not sequential(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have to be numerical? Or can it be alphanumeric?

Comment: That's cool, you have a couple of answers to look at which should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is insane, but here is my way of generating the Customer Numbers up front.

This will generate however many UNIQUE keys you want *very quickly*.

You could obviously save these into a real table.

Here is a **SQLFiddle** of the below: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/3884

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CustNo INT UNIQUE
)

DECLARE @Upper INT
DECLARE @Lower INT
DECLARE @NumberRequired INT

SET @Lower = 100000 ---- The lowest random number allowed
SET @Upper = 999999 ---- The highest random number allowed
SET @NumberRequired = 1000 -- How many IDs do we want?

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl) < @NumberRequired
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT (ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0))
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- If it goes wrong go round the loop again
    END CATCH
END

SELECT  *
FROM    @tbl
```

**EDIT: Actually this is probably faster. It generates all 900000 possible keys in around 30 seconds on my dev machine, which is okay for a one-off job.**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    ID INT
)

DECLARE @Upper INT
DECLARE @Lower INT
DECLARE @i INT;

SET @Lower = 100000 ---- The lowest random number allowed
SET @Upper = 999999 ---- The highest random number allowed

SET @i = @Lower

WHILE @i <= @Upper
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT @i
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT  ID
FROM    @tbl ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Neat, but it will get much slower as the number of remaining keys decreases.

Comment: Yeah that's true! But surely anything method would suffer from that problem wouldn't it? It was very quick for 1000 keys (sub second) and less than ten seconds for 10,000 keys on my poor dev machine at work. If Dominic is worried about people seeing sequential keys then that might be enough to generate up front?! Especially since this is a one-off exercise.

Answer (score 4):

If you choose any increment that is not a factor of 1000000, then you could take the last 6 digits of that number to provide the ID; ie `(IDENTITY (1,7)) % 1000000`.

But your competitors could still find the increment by a few sequential registrations, so this would not completely solve the issue.

So it would seem you want a number that is completely random - so for that, you'll have to check whether it already exists when you generate it, or pre-generate a list of numbers, sort them randomly, and pick the next when creating a new customer.

Another option to consider is some form of encryption, if you can find or create an appropriate algorithm that creates a short enough output.

If you take the large non factor increment route, you could then subsequently re-arrange the order of the digits to create a more random number - eg;

```
declare @inc int , @loop int
declare @t table (i int, cn int, code varchar(4))

select @inc = 5173, @loop = 1
while @loop<=10000
begin
    insert @t (i, cn)
    select @loop, (@inc*@loop)%10000
    select @loop = @loop + 1
end

update @t 
set code = substring(convert(varchar(4),cn),2,1)
    + substring(convert(varchar(4),cn),4,1)
    + substring(convert(varchar(4),cn),3,1)
    + substring(convert(varchar(4),cn),1,1)

select code, count(*) from @t group by code having count(*)>1
select top 20 * from @t order by i
```

Depending on the number you choose, some sequential items will have the same difference between them, but this number will vary. So it's not *cryptographically* secure, but probably enough to thwart all but the most determined of competitors.

You could convert the above to a function to run off a standard `IDENTITY(1,1)` id field

Answer (score 0):

You can have calculated column that generated from Identity column and create unique value that Expect.

for example calculated column like below :

100000 + Identity_Column * 7 + 3

Comment: Identify column is unique and surely above calculate column be unique.

Answer (score 0):

What if juts use user registration timestamp. It doesn't contain user's count information and unique (If you don't register users each second for example). For instance if you use 10000 in this query you can register users each minute and get unique 9 symbol digit:

```
select cast(cast(current_timestamp as float)*10000 as int)
```

Comment: I don't think 6 digits give a big enough range of numbers so that this would work for fast registrations.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a table with 2 columns, one with the values 100.000 to 999.999 and one with a marker whether the number has been given out. When making a new client assign an unassigned number from this table at random and mark it assigned.

Comment: actually a table with one column and removing the used numbers would also work. You could pre-randomize the table.